# How to write a unit test to read input via Console.ReadLine()

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I'm trying to learn Nunit and need to write a unit test for user input on console as below:

```
 command = Console.ReadLine() ?? "";
 var enteredText = command.ToLower();
 if (enteredText.Contains("add general"))
 {
    string[] passengerSegments = enteredText.Split(' ');
    _scheduledFlight.AddPassenger(new Passenger
    {
        Type = PassengerType.General, 
        Name = passengerSegments[2], 
        Age = Convert.ToInt32(passengerSegments[3])
    });
 }
```

I'm splitting the user input on space and then inserting them to fill my Passenger object but the input might be lacking a value or a wrong data type.

I can write a method to validate the user input, but how can I write a unit test for this?

Comment: Despite your title, the ReadLine is the part you do _not_ want to unit test.

Comment: @Henk you mean we can't do any testing on this kind of userinput using ReadLine? All we need is some sort of validation